# local variable 'rec_sistrade' referenced before assignment

Tags: sql-server, django, postgresql

Me sale error referenced before assigment en rec, como podria solucionarlo?
Necesito pasarle rec y emp preciso como podria pasarlo sin que me salga el error referenced before asigment?

```
def show_trabajos(request):
      hostname = socket.gethostname()
      ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
      qs = info_equipos.objects.all().filter(ip=ip_add)
      
      for q in qs:
       rec = q.rec
       emp = request.user.user

      ## sentencia 1
      sentencia = "exec [Pr].[dbo].[PT_GGET]" +  str(rec) + "," + emp
      cursor.execute(sentencia) 
      results = namedtuplefetchall(cursor)
```

Comment: lo mismo es que `qs` es vacío y `rec` nunca se define

Answer (score 0):

Primero necesitas verificar que tu queryset qs no sea vacío antes de hacer un ciclo for, posteriormente tienes que inicializar la variable rec y verificar que exista antes de poder ejecutar la sentencia. Y ya que quieres usar request.user.user primero necesitas cerciorarte que el usuario ya inicio sesión, puedes usar el decorador login_required.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def show_trabajos(request):
    hostname = socket.gethostname()
    ip_add = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    qs = info_equipos.objects.all().filter(ip=ip_add)

    rec = None # inicializa rec
    emp = None # inicializa emp

    if qs: # Verifica que qs no este vacio
        for q in qs:
            rec = q.rec
            emp = request.user.user
    ## sentencia 1
    if rec and emp: # verifica que rec no sea None ni emp sea None para poder ejecutar la sentencia
        sentencia = "exec [Pr].[dbo].[PT_GGET]" +  str(rec) + "," + emp
        cursor.execute(sentencia) 
        results = namedtuplefetchall(cursor)
```